# Google Speech API Java Client does not work on my computer

Tags: java, eclipse, google-speech-api

When I am using the Java API Client for Google Speech API, the program hangs on this line:

```
SyncRecognizeResponse response = speech.syncRecognize(config, audio);
```

When I run this code as a Java Application, everything works. When my colleagues run this same exact code, as a Java Application or Web service, it works.

I am using Java 1.8, Apache 9.0, and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Neon 4.6.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```
public class  ConvertSpeechToText{

@GET
public Response process() {

    String response1 = "{\"message\" : \"%s\"}";
    SpeechClient speech = null;
    try {
        speech = SpeechClient.create();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // The path to the audio file to transcribe
    String fileName = "/Users/jasocarter/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/yes.flac";

    // Reads the audio file into memory
    File file = new File(fileName);
    java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
    System.out.println(audioBytes);

 // Builds the sync recognize request
    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
        .setSampleRate(5)
        .build();

    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
        .setContent(audioBytes)
        .build();

    // Builds the sync recognize request for FLAC content
    /*RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
        .setSampleRate(16000)
        .build();
    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
        .setUri("gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac")
        .build();*/

    // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
    SyncRecognizeResponse response = speech.syncRecognize(config, audio);
    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

    for (SpeechRecognitionResult result: results) {
      List<SpeechRecognitionAlternative> alternatives = result.getAlternativesList();
      for (SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative: alternatives) {
        System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
        response1 = String.format(response1, alternative.getTranscript());
      }
    }

    try
    {
        speech.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return Response.status(200).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(response1).build();

}
```

}

Comment: It is possible that it is refers to this issue? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/723

Comment: I got the same issue. Were u able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous mode only allows up to 1 minute, if you need to transcribe an audio of more than 1 minute, you must use Google Cloud Storage.